# How to skip saturday and sunday in a cron expression?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, quartz-scheduler

Hi I want to create a cron expression excluding saturday and sunday.

Comment: Did you read the `crontab(5)` man page e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab ?

Comment: I really don't see why this question 'is not on topic'.

Comment: This is off topic because it has nothing to do with programming in the normal definition, but is more related to server administration.  Therefore, https://serverfault.com/ is the proper place for this question (even if it's for a workstation crontab settings are still most often used on servers).  One could loosely say it is programming the computer, but it's not programming as most people would define it.

Comment: @JRoysdon thank goodness for your explanation. It can be very difficult on this site to deal with open-loop feedback, where something is deemed bad, but you have very little idea why it was deemed bad and therefore are unsure how to prevent a similar mistake in the future. In your case, you closed the loop with the feedback and it can be a good signal to future posters where the lines are between programming-specific and otherwise more computer-related questions not specific to programming, as well as where the more appropriate place to post is. Again, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz JRoysdon Your are both joking right ? Of course cron expression are about programming, just like regexp. You can't use CronTriggers from Quartz framework without knowledge about cron expressions : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html I vote for reopen an obviously useful question.

Comment: See similar "on-topic" question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds/9619441

Comment: `cron` is a general scheduling syntax, used in many programming libraries, this seems on topic to me.

Answer (score 138):

Begin the line with `0 0 * * 1,2,3,4,5 <user> <command>`. The first fields are minutes and hours. In this case the command will run at midnight. The stars mean: for every day of the month, and for every month. The 1 to 5 specify the days. monday to friday. 6=saturday 0=sunday.

Comment: 1-5 works too..

Comment: Best way,
0 0 * * 1-5 <script name>

Comment: At 9am every day from M-F: ' 0 9 * * 1-5 ' tested on https://crontab.guru

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
# run every two hours at the top of the hour Monday through Friday
0 */2 * * mon-fri <command>
```

Comment: "Use the first three letters of the particular day or month (case doesn't matter). **Ranges or lists of names are not allowed.**"

Comment: @scribu I guess it's relative to the cron daemon you use. In my case `dcron` which Slackware ships with does support this feature, it's even one of their examples.

Comment: https://crontab.guru/#*/10_*_*_*_1,2,3,4,5 it is very easy: “At every 10th minute on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.”

Answer (score -1):

To sum it up simples, **0** represents **Sunday** and **6 Saturday**:

- */10 * * * 1-5 - At every 10th minute on very day-of-week from Monday through Friday.
- */10 * * * 0,6 - At every 10th minute on Sunday and Saturday.