# Cron Scheduler use case

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am stuck and seek your help for my requirement , where I need to run a job everyday except on Sunday mornings from 05:30 AM to 08:30 AM.

I have searched and could not see the solution for my problem, could you be able to help me out to get the correct Cron Expression. I have also tried it using http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) is a better cron maker. Try this and let us know how it went.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip the cron job in saturday and sunday in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143965/how-to-skip-the-cron-job-in-saturday-and-sunday-in-linux)

Comment: what time of the day, you run your job?

Comment: It needs to  be running continuously except those timings given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the easiest solution in cron is:

1. start your program without any limit
2. stop your code at 5:30 AM on sundays

   30 5 * * 7   stop_code
3. start your code at 8:30 Am on sundays

   30 8 * * 7   start_code_again

Comment: this would be a terrible solution. You would have the application either executed one time: at 8:30 on sundays, or it would be active constantly, but you would have to check in the code itself for when to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your response.

I have used a CronRoutePolicy with respect to Camel as we were using Camel.

In the route policy i could define Start time , Suspend Time and Resume Time.

I have deployed it but some how quartz has not started the job. Figuring out the issue now.